# .draggable(); functionality not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Project 507</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#draggable {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#draggable").draggable();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="draggable">
<p>Compose new Tweet</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `.draggable();` functionality is not working. I have placed it in a `<div>` and used jQuery to try and make this `<p>` work. However there is something wrong with this code and its not outputting the `.draggable();` function. Can i get some help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery-ui.js in your code :
For reference you can have a look on this :
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jennifersam/a1cpdwar/)

Code is as below

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Except this all code is same.